# Изменение шрифта и размера текста без изменения предыдущих настроек форматирования

Tags: c#, winforms

Работа состоит в том, что я ставлю на разные куски текста разные стили и размер шрифта. А потом выделяю все измененные куски и ставлю им один шрифт. Результатом должно быть: текст стоит выбранным шрифтом из `ComboBox`, а их стили и размеры не изменяются самовольно. На данный момент все происходит наоборот. Ставлю кускам текста разные стили и размер, выделяю все, ставлю всем один шрифт и все предыдущее форматирование слетает.

Вот что имеется:

```
private void FontBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RichTextBox.SelectionFont != null)
    {             
        RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(FontBox.Text, RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Size, RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Style);
    }
    RichTextBox.Select();
}

private void SizeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    float size = 12;
    if (SizeBox.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        size = Convert.ToSingle(SizeBox.Text);               
    }
    RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox.SelectionFont.FontFamily, size, RichTextBox.SelectionFont.Style);
}
```

В чем ошибка мне известно. Программа всему выделенному присваивает один размер и один стиль. Вопрос в другом. Как программу заставить сохранять свои размеры и стиль при присваивании `new Font()`? Неужели надо делать все посимвольно через цикл?

P.S. Также кстати должно работать когда выбираю размер текста, также через `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Понятие шрифт в .NET включает в себя почти все параметры шрифта, за исключением разве что цветов текста и фона.
2. **[System.Drawing.Font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx)** неизменяем, это видно из того, что все его свойства доступны только для чтения. Следовательно вы не сможете у созданного шрифта поменять, например, размер не создав для этого новый объект `Font`
3. Посимвольно разумеется не стоит, т.к. такое решение с большой вероятностью будет генерировать ужасную rtf-разметку текста. Для решения вашей задачи скорее всего придется разбираться с форматом `RTF` и делать все на низком уровне, т.е. "руками" править rtf-разметку, т.к. `RichTextBox`, не смотря на все его достоинства, является всего лишь базовым элементом, поддерживающим отображение `RTF` и весьма скромно поддерживающим форматирование текста.